# Horizontal and vertical splitting via parallel transport

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

Let $\{e_i\}$ be local frame on a Riemannian manifold, constructed as follows: let $\{\hat e_i\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $T_yM$ for some $y\in M$ fixed, and define in a small neighbourhood $U$ of $y$ the vector fields $e_i(x):=P_{\gamma_x}(\hat e_i)(1)$, where $\gamma_x$ is the unique unit speed geodesic from $y$ to $x$, and $P$ denotes the parallel transport system associated to the Levi Civita connection. Let now $\delta(t)$ be a geodesic in $U$. My question is

> Is it true that $\frac{d}{dt}\big\vert_{t=0}e_i(\delta(t))$ is horizontal?

This is true by definition of the frame if $\delta=\gamma_x$, and if the connection is flat. But is it still true in the general case? And if not, is there a way to characterise "how far it is from being horizontal"?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by horizontal? Do you mean that the curve in the orthonormal frame bundle is horizontal?

Comment: If you mean that the $e_i$ are parallel along each geodesic in $U,$ then the answer is no. This would imply that $\nabla_{e_i}e_{j}=0$ on $U,$ for all $i,j$, and hence the curvature on $U$ would vanish. In fact the curvature is a good measure for this.

Comment: Yes exactly, that what I meant. Perfect, it makes sense. Is there an explicit way to quantify this through the curvature?

Comment: What does $d/dt|_{t=0} e_i(\delta(t))$ even mean? Are you using the covariant derivative and intending $D/dt|_{t=0} e_i(\delta(t))$?

Comment: Since $t\mapsto e_i(\delta(t))$ is a curve in $TM$, the derivative in $0$ is an element of $TTM$. Considering the splitting into horizontal and vertical components $TTM=\mathscr{H}\oplus \mathscr{V}TM$, where $\mathscr{H}$ is the horizontal distribution associated to the connection, my question was $\frac{d}{dt}\vert_{t=0}e_i(\delta(t))\in \mathscr{H}$? If the connection is not flat this is not the case (thank you @Terje). I would like to know if "how far is it from being horizontal" has something to do with the curvature.